# finding and replacing strings with numbers only within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the strings that contain numbers with another string (an empty one in this case) within a pandas DataFrame.

I tried with the .replace method and a regex expression:

```
# creating dummy dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['test' for _ in range(5)]})

# the value that should get replaced with ''
data.iloc[0] = 'test5' 

data.replace(regex=r'\d', value='', inplace=True)

print(data)

      A
0  test
1  test
2  test
3  test
4  test
```

As you can see, it only replace the '5' within the string and not the whole string.

I also tried using the .where method but it doesn't seem to fit my need as I don't want to replace any of the strings not containing numbers

this is what it should look like:

```
      A
0  
1  test
2  test
3  test
4  test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing via [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
data.loc[data['A'].str.contains(r'\d'), 'A'] = ''
```

Similarly, with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`np.where`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data['A'] = data['A'].mask(data['A'].str.contains(r'\d'), '')
data['A'] = np.where(data['A'].str.contains(r'\d'), '', data['A'])
```